# Use jQuery to replace span content with field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

I want to have form fields, when populated and a button clicked will change the contents of span's within html. I have tried the following but the span contents aren't being replaced.

I have written the following html:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">
            Name
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameValue" />
    </div>
    <button id="generate" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            Generate Story
    </button>
</form>

<p>The persons name is <span id="name"></span></p>
```

Then have written the following jQuery:

```
<script>

$(function() {
  $("button").click( function()
       {
            $("#nameValue").keyup(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $("#name").html(val);
            });
       }
  );
});

</script>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/074ynshn/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating `keyup`, `click` event handlers , setting `button` `disabled` to `true` if no value at `"#nameValue"` , setting `button` `disabled` to `false` at `keyup` event

```js
$(function() {
  var button = $("button"),
    val = "";
  $("#nameValue").keyup(function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    if (val.length > 0 && /\w+/.test(val)) button.prop("disabled", false)
  });
  button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#name").html(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">
      Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameValue" />
  </div>
  <button id="generate" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled="true">
    Generate Story
  </button>
</form>

<p>The persons name is <span id="name"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Worked exactly as I needed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will change span value after button click and on keyup

```
   <script>

    $(function() {
        $("button").click( function(){
            changeSpanValue($("#nameValue").val());
        });

        $("#nameValue").keyup(function() {
            changeSpanValue($(this).val());
        });
    });

    function changeSpanValue(val){
       $("#name").html(val);
    }

   </script>
```